# Boxplot with ggsubseriesplot() for time series analysis

Tags: boxplot

How to use boxplot with ggsubseriesplot in R, any idea?

```
library(forecast)
ggsubseriesplot(AirPassengers)
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is probably just to swap the existing layers to a boxplot layer:

```r
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggsubseriesplot(AirPassengers)
p$layers <- list(geom_boxplot())
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>